# Load facebook logout URL using an Iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, iframe, widget, logout

How can I load my facebook logout URL without redirecting to the site using an Iframe

I have a code but does not go according to plan,

my.js

```
var url = https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=mysite.com&access_token=mytoken

var disp = "";
disp += "<iframe src =" + datafile + "></iframe>";

$.(".setContent").append(disp);
```

It will show the iframe, but when I load the url on a page, still my account hasn't logged out. I'm loading this on my windows gadget.

Comment: I think Facebook will refuse to log out unless the referrer is from within Facebook, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook would not allow that, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not allow any of its pages to be contained within an `iframe`. You should try opening a new tab or a popup window.